# Creating Overlay Control in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using c# winforms to show an Image. The displaying of the image is done using a user control. Now I want to provide the user to draw lines, put other small images, write text etc over the image on an overlay control. How can I provide this functionality? If I use another user control to show the overlay control with transparent back, will that work?? any other solution will be welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try approaching this with a canvas ([Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx)) that handles painting the image as the background and all the annotations/markup afterwards.  This will make the foreground appear to be transparent.  I expect you'll want to set [Control.DoubleBuffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.doublebuffered.aspx) for performance.

You might experiment with setting the style [ControlStyles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlstyles.aspx).AllPaintingInWmPaint.  Also, try overriding [Control.OnPaintBackground](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaintbackground.aspx) and do nothing, and override [Control.OnPaint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint.aspx) and do all your painting inside there.

If performance is still unacceptable, pay close attention to the PaintEventArgs.ClipRect property.  This is the only area you need to paint.  The trick is figuring out which of your annotations/overlays intersect with this rectangle and painting them in the correct order.

Either this canvas or a higher level control will need to track mouse movement so you know where to draw the lines, paste images, etc.

Comment: +1 for recommendation to `DoubleBuffer`, this will reduce flicker. Great advice all around. I've done this with multiple panels overlaying a background. And you are right about tracking mouse movement, it becomes a real challenge. The advantage of Panels as the canvas over using a Rectangle is that the Panel has built in mouse tracking.